# Import CSV file in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, import, bulkinsert

I want to import csv data in sql server. I searched about and found answers about BULK INSERT ... FROM.

The problem I have is :

- I want to select just one column of my results
- The table already exists with bad datas and I just want to update these fields

The CSV I had contains towns and its parameters (correct datas)

```
Town,Id,ZipCode,...
T1,1,12000
T2,2,12100
T3,3,12200
```

And the table in SQL Server 'town' contains for example
    T1,1,30456
    T2,2,36327
    T3,3,85621

I just want to get ZipCode in CSV and update the ZipCode in the table in function the ID.
Does it exist an easy way to do it ?

Comment: Can you bulk insert to a temp table and then update your `town` table by joining it to the temp table on `Id`?

Comment: You could also look into using SSIS.

Comment: Another option is to use `OPENROWSET` and read directly from the csv file. You can treat it like a table and update using a `join`.

Answer (score 0):

I normally prefer bcp over bulk insert because with that you can easily import the files over network and there's less issues with access rights. Otherwise I would just load the data into tempdb and update the original table from there.